# Unwanted Characters in CSV

Tags: csv, apache-spark

Trying to save a csv file from spark but when I open up the file in vim I get the following characters and I don't understand what they mean or how they are getting into the file. [image]

Here is my writer from spark:

```
df.write.partitionBy(partitionCol).format("csv").mode(writeMode)
  .option("sep", ",")
  .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
  .option("quote", "")
  .option("escape", "\\")
  .option("escapeQuotes", true)
  .option("quoteAll", true)
  .option("header", hasHeader)
  .option("nullValue", "")
  .option("dateFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  .option("timestampFormat", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ")
  .option("compression", "gzip")
  .save(outPath)
```

Comment: how are you saving? and what is the data before you save? provide all the details

Comment: Is your csv file encoding unicode or something else? try ro set encode option when you write your dataframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.write):

> "quote – sets a single character used for escaping quoted values where the separator can be part of the value. If None is set, it uses the default value, ". **If an empty string is set, it uses u0000 (null character)**."

So, as you're setting `quote` to be an empty string, you're getting null bytes as quotes (traditionally represented as "^@" in [caret notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation).)